# Install .NET Core on Google Colab

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install .NET Core on Google Colab. I follow the instructions given (for Ubuntu 17.10):

```
! wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/17.10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
! dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
! apt-get install apt-transport-https
! apt-get update
```

This all works fine until I try to install aspnetcore-runtime-2.1 :

```
! apt-get install aspnetcore-runtime-2.1
```

and get this error :

```
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aspnetcore-runtime-2.1 : Depends: dotnet-runtime-2.1 (>= 2.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

You can clearly see that there is a dependency missing : dotnet-runtime-2.1. The problem is I cannot manage to install it separately so there is no dependency issue. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Do you want `aspnetcore-runtime-2.1` this version specifically?

Comment: No I just want to install the .NET core sdk

Comment: Thus is the tutorial I found on medium : https://medium.com/@MatthewMooreZA/google-colab-net-core-c0c1cd80661d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google colab is on ubuntu version 18.04.3 at the moment. You can check it using,

`! lsb_release -a`

So you need to follow [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1804) for that version.
Execute these steps one after the other, in order.

```
! wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
! dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
! add-apt-repository universe
! apt-get update
! apt-get install apt-transport-https
! apt-get update
! apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

Here is a working colab notebook -> https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19ZM4sIccSOgNjX3hQW0KUFsVbZCrGXTY

You can check if it got installed properly using,

```
! dotnet --list-sdks
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have another question. I tried to install a package (`! dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp`), successful installation. Though I cannot execute it (It gives me this error : `Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.`). After the instalation of the package this message appeared : (`===Since you just installed the .NET Core SDK, you will need to logout or restart your session before running the tool you installed.`)  I then restarted the runtime but it still didn't work, any tips ?

Comment: What is the command you are using to execute `Microsoft.Quantum.IQSharp`

Comment: `! dotnet iqsharp install`

Comment: I believe all the functionalities are not possible in colab environment. I found this issue https://github.com/microsoft/iqsharp/issues/14 see if that helps

Comment: Tremendously helpful, you've saved me having to do a 2-hour drive to get my pc!